# Substitution in Integration about log

Tags: integration

A question on my book:
$$\int{\frac{1}{x(\log{x})^n}dx}$$where n is an integer.

What I did:
Let u=$\frac{1}{\log{x}}$, then $\frac{du}{dx}=x, dx=\frac{du}{x}.$

Now the integral becomes $$\int{\frac{1}{xu^n}dx}=\int{\frac{1}{xu^n}\times {\frac{du}{x}}}$$

I don't know what to do next. Should I change another u?
Note: if possible, please use substitution to solve the problem.

Comment: $\dfrac{\mathrm d u}{\mathrm d x}=-\dfrac1{x\log^2x}$, not $\;\dfrac1{\log' x}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the substitution $u=\log x$ and so $du=\frac{1}{x}dx$. Hence,$$
\int \frac{1}{x(\log x)^n}\,dx=\int\frac{(\log x)^{-n}}{x}\,dx=\int u^{-n}\,du.
$$
Then, for $n\geq 2$, we get$$
\int u^{-n}\,du=\frac{u^{1-n}}{1-n}=\frac{(\log x)^{1-n}}{1-n}.
$$
For $n=1$, we get$$
\int u^{-1}\,du=\log u=\log(\log x).
$$

Comment: Not true if $n=1$.

Answer (score 5):

Call $u=\log x$, then $du = dx/x$ and your integral becomes

$$
\int\frac{dx}{x\log^n x} = \int\frac{du}{u^n} = \cdots
$$